# Code cleanup adds spaces in interpolated strings

Tags: c#, resharper, code-cleanup

I have a problem with Resharper code cleanup, it turns out that there is some collision/setting in my editor config that causes spaces to be added in the interpolated text, spoiling the result. The problem does not occur in Rider, but it is also unlikely to be related to the code cleanup in VS (turned it off).
Has anyone perhaps hit such a problem or knows a setting to get rid of it without giving up autoformatting altogether?
Cheers

[image: BeforeAfterCodeCleanUp]

Here is part of my editor config:

```
resharper_space_in_singleline_accessorholder = false
resharper_space_in_singleline_anonymous_method = false
resharper_space_in_singleline_method = false
resharper_space_near_postfix_and_prefix_op = false
resharper_space_within_array_initialization_braces = false
resharper_space_within_array_rank_empty_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_array_rank_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_attribute_angles = false
resharper_space_within_checked_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_default_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_empty_braces = false
resharper_space_within_empty_initializer_braces = false
resharper_space_within_empty_invocation_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_empty_method_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_empty_template_params = false
resharper_space_within_expression_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_initializer_braces = false
resharper_space_within_invocation_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_method_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_nameof_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_new_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_single_line_array_initializer_braces = false
resharper_space_within_sizeof_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_template_args = false
resharper_space_within_template_params = false
resharper_space_within_tuple_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_typeof_parentheses = false
resharper_space_within_type_argument_angles = false
resharper_space_within_type_parameter_angles = false
resharper_space_within_type_parameter_parentheses = false
```

Comment: [Raising an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP) for this seems like a reasonable idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens to be a known issue - [Raw string literal formatting](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-489718/Raw-string-literal-formatting) that should be already fixed in ReSharper 2022.3 version. Could you please check if you are using this version or later one?